# c++ vector subscript out of range omp locks

Tags: c++, openmp

I want to use lock on a complete lock if any thread is adding a new value in that row. For this purpose I have write the following code:

```
std::vector <omp_lock_t> ds_lock;
```

I am initializing locks in constructor

```
Sparse_Matrix_RL::Sparse_Matrix_RL(unsigned int row_size, unsigned int col_size)
{
    row_sz = row_size;
    col_sz = col_size;
    omp_init_lock(&ds_lock[0]);
}
```

And here I am using it

```
void Sparse_Matrix_RL::addValue(unsigned int rid, unsigned int cid, double value)
{
    omp_set_lock(&ds_lock[rid]);

    if (value == 0) 
    {
        omp_unset_lock(&ds_lock[rid]);
        return;
    }
    std::map<unsigned int, double>::iterator str = data_Matrix[rid].begin();
    std::map<unsigned int, double>::iterator end = data_Matrix[rid].end();
    str = data_Matrix[rid].find(cid);
    //while (str->first != cid && str != end) str++;
    if (str != end)
        str->second += value;
    else
        data_Matrix[rid][cid] = value;
    omp_unset_lock(&ds_lock[rid]);
}
```

When I run the code it gives me error:

> vector subscript out of range

Now I am not understanding where I am wrong.

Comment: Are you adding any elements to `ds_lock`?

Comment: @P.W no i am not. just locking the row that is being modify

Comment: Aside: I wouldn't make a sparse matrix from a `std::map<unsigned, std::map<unsigned, double>>`, but instead have a `std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, double>`. You also don't need distinguish between the case where `rid, cid` is present or not, `operator[]` will give you a zero-initialised `double&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector `ds_lock` does not have any elements in it and you are accessing the address of the first element in the constructor of `Sparse_Matrix_RL` in the below statement.

```
omp_init_lock(&ds_lock[0]);
```

You have to use either [`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) or [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to add elements and only then try to access its elements.

Comment: but I don't want to add elements in it. just want to lock a complete row

Comment: Then you don't need a vector of locks, you just need one lock. Something like: `omp_lock_t lock; omp_init_lock(lock);`

Comment: but it locks the whole data structure. how it will lock a single row?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. But to access an element of a vector at a particular `index`, it should have `index+1` elements in it. Otherwise you will get "vector subscript out of range" error.